# Determine remainder when N is divided by 1000?

Tags: combinatorics, contest-math, combinations

**Question:**

If N denotes the number of $7$ digit positive integers having property that their digits are in non-decreasing order
then, find $N \pmod {1000}$

(assume that repeated digits are allowed)

**My attempt:**

I am familiar with the case when repetition is not allowed  in that case answer 
is simply found by picking 7 numbers out of 9 in $^9C_7$ =36 ways (or by removing 2 digits from any 9 digit number ,having digits sorted previously  in increasing order,in $^9C_2$ ways).

but, I don't know how to do the aforesaid question in which repetition of digits is allowed with only restriction that digits from left to right must be in ascending order.

**edited:** replaced "increasing order" with "non-decreasing order".

Comment: @ krirkrirk :  i just want the value of 'N'  then, (N mod 1000) follows from there....... it is basically counting problem.

Comment: "increasing order" excludes repetition of digits. If repetion is allowed then that must change into "non-decreasing order".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an answer if repetition of digits is allowed and the digits are demanded to be in non-decreasing order (weaker than increasing order).

For $i=1,\dots,9$ let $n_i$ denotes the number of occurences of digit $i$.

Then $N$ equals the number of sums $n_1+\dots+n_9=7$ where the $n_i$ are nonnegative integers.

E.g. solution $\langle 1,0,3,0,0,2,0,0,1\rangle$ corresponds with number $1333669$.

This can be solved with [stars and bars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)) and we find:$$N=\binom{7+8}{8}$$

Comment: @ dr hab :your answer is correct sir, but  please explain more in physical sense ,that  why you used stars bar here . i mean how do i know it's a star bar problem.i'm only aware of using  stars bars technique  only when identical objects (say candies) are distributed among different persons or like identical balls are to be dropped into distinguishable bins.....i'm not able to connect it in this problem what are balls and what are bins ....help me please

Comment: Think of $7$ identical balls that are dropped in $9$ distinguishable bins. If e.g. $3$ balls end up in bin $2$ then digit $2$ appears $3$ times in the $7$-digit number.

Comment: You are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

Hint : If digits of the number are in increasing order, none of the two digits can be same. So the problem is equivalent to find number of such combinations, with no repetition of digits at all.

Comment: sir, can i say cases like ,1111122,2222223,....1111223,1122334,1234556,1233458 are valid .since digits must be in increasing order according to the problem and also since repetition is allowed so, i have used any digit any number of times.

Comment: $11$ isn't a number with increasing order of digits. It's non-decreasing. Increasing means, the digits must be greater on moving left to right. $11$ isn't accepted, but$12$ is. You got it?

Comment: sorry , i got it , it should be non decreasing.thank you